# get dbo.AspNetUserLogins info .NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have .NET Core Web API app with external login via Google, Microsoft providers feature.
I can sign in or sign up user via external providers or standard (built-in) auth.
As I know, when I sign in user via external provider, I add user login info to `dbo.AspNetUserLogins` in the following way:

```
var loginInfo = await this._signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, loginInfo);
```

I want to do the following:

when user was signed up for example via Google, then if the same user is tried to sign in via standard auth or Microsoft I need to notify this user that he can sign in only via Google.
So, I need to extract `dbo.AspNetUserLogins` data for this user somehow or define what provider user used for registration.

Maybe I need to add this table to my DBContext? Are there other ways to do it (without changing DB context)? Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.